# Cannot select text with css without html element tag

Tags: html, css, label, less

I have an auto-generated file input form element:

```
<div id="university_logo">
  <img src=/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="id_univercity_logo">Logo</label>
        <div class="row bootstrap3-multi-input">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            Currently: 
            <a href="/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg">userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg</a><br />
            Change:
            <input type="file" name="univercity_logo" autocomplete="off" class="" title="" id="id_univercity_logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I am trying to remove the labels "Currently:" and "Change:"**

My css code is:

```
#university_logo {
  .form-group{
    .row{
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      .col-xs-12{
        *:not(#id_univercity_logo){
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the two labels don't disappear.

**Can I select a label without a label tag?**

Comment: what you want to do ..?

Comment: I have written it in the post: "I am trying to remove the labels "Currently:" and "Change:" It's in bold, too.

Comment: I am trying to remove the labels "Currently:" and "Change:"    , but you have one label called `logo` ? whats the problem?

Comment: I do have two other texts that appear like labels but don't have any html tags.

Comment: oky so you want to hide it, simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use `visibility`

```css
.col-xs-12 {
visibility:collapse; /*hidden, in this case same result*/
font-size: 0px;
}

.col-xs-12 input{
    visibility:visible;
}

.col-xs-12 a{
    visibility:visible;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="university_logo">
  <img src=/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="id_univercity_logo">Logo</label>
        <div class="row bootstrap3-multi-input">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            Currently: 
            <a href="/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg">Image Tag</a><br />
            Change:
            <input type="file" name="univercity_logo" autocomplete="off" class="" title="" id="id_univercity_logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: @HenryLynx pleasure, happy coding!

Comment: @HenryLynx, maybe change header from `Cannot select label without label tag` to `Cannot select text with css without html element tag`
`

Comment: However, this way only the visibility changes but the elements are still there. I've changed the height to 0px and it looks fine now.

Comment: you would want to remove the element space aswell?

Answer (score 0):

try `css code` this way

```css
#university_logo .form-group .row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="university_logo">
  <img src=/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="id_univercity_logo">Logo</label>
    <div class="row bootstrap3-multi-input">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Currently:
        <a href="/media/userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg">userprofile/Metallica_-_2008_-_Death_Magnetic_-_Front.jpg</a><br /> Change:
        <input type="file" name="univercity_logo" autocomplete="off" class="" title="" id="id_univercity_logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can still see the "Currently" and "Change" text. That is what I need to get as a result.

Comment: You are running the same code as I. Why do you expect a different result? Ylama's answer works.